# Response json not equals to sql query

Tags: spring-boot

I need the user id, user name, asesor nombre, asesor telefono, asesor correo and the tipo asesor but the json response repeat data.

this is the sql query in the spring reposotiry.

'''

```
@Query( value = "SELECT U.id as userid, u.name as cliente," +
"A.nombre, A.correo, A.telefono, TA.tipo as asesoria " +
"from tc_users U, tc_usuario_asesores UA , " +
"tc_asesor A,tc_tip_asesor TA " +
"where U.id = UA.userid " +
"and UA.asesorid= A.id " +
"and A.tipo_asesor = TA.id",
 nativeQuery = true)
```

'''

and this query in sql workbench return this data

[query in sql workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM3R4.png)

but the json response return this data

[Json response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swJQE.png)

and dont know because this haappend, a need help with this, sorry for my bad inglish.

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns a cartesian product because of the join.

You can add DISTINCT to get unique rows.

```
@Query( value = "SELECT DISTINCT U.id as userid, u.name as cliente," +
"A.nombre, A.correo, A.telefono, TA.tipo as asesoria " +
"from tc_users U, tc_usuario_asesores UA , " +
"tc_asesor A,tc_tip_asesor TA " +
"where U.id = UA.userid " +
"and UA.asesorid= A.id " +
"and A.tipo_asesor = TA.id",
 nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: I try with Select Distinct but the json response return the same repeat data, I tryind with 
different querys and i get the same bad result

Comment: what do you do with the data after you get it from the query?

Comment: after going through the repository, the data goes through the service and then through the controller, I just need to display the data, I don't need to modify it

Comment: So show your code

Comment: Place the code as an answer in this same question as additional information.